# Reading a JSON Array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, json, jdbc

I'm having a problem reading JSON Array because inside my array, there's another array and I'm confused.Please see my code.

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
    JSONObject obj = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
    JSONObject jsonObjectReturn =  JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();

    //JSONOBJECT RETURN
    JSONArray array = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONArray();



        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            callableStatement = (CallableStatement) conn
                    .prepareCall("{call TaxpaymentSPv2(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");


            callableStatement.setString(1, obj.getString("rdoCode"));
            callableStatement.setString(2, obj.getString("rcoCode"));
            callableStatement.setString(3, obj.getString("tpTin"));
            callableStatement.setString(4,  obj.getString("tpName")); 
            callableStatement.setString(5, obj.getString("tpAddress"));
            callableStatement.setString(6, obj.getString("receiptType"));
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(7, Types.VARCHAR);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(8, Types.VARCHAR);

            callableStatement.executeUpdate();

            String rNo = callableStatement.getString(7);
            String date = callableStatement.getString(8);


            //---->This is my second Array inside my JSON where im having an error <------
            String checkArray = obj.getString("checkArray");
            JSONArray jsonArrayCheck = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONArray(stringArray);


            JSONArray jsonArray2 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("checkArray");
            System.out.println("..........." + jsonArray2);

            jsonObjectReturn =  JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();
            jsonObjectReturn.put("rNo", rNo);
            jsonObjectReturn.put("date", date);
            array.put(jsonObjectReturn);
        }

        return array;
```

Here's my JSON input:

```
{
"dataArray": [{

"rdoCode": "001",
"rcoCode": "002911",
"tpTin": "200746409",
"tpName": "JOHN DOE",
"tpAddress": "LA CALIFORNIA",
"receiptType":"ROR",
"receiptMode":"AUTO",
"manualReceiptNo":"",
"checkArray":[{
"ptchkNumber": 14546,
"ptchkDate": 2014-01-01,
"ptchkAmount": 5332,
"ptchkStatus": ""
}]
}]
}
```

I can't parse the **"checkArray"** object that gives me this error. `com.liferay.portal.kernel.json.JSONException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]`. Can someone tell me what to do? Thanks.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @user2182349 i'm using java

Comment: I believe `"ptchkDate": 2014-01-01` will be treated as a number and your field `ptchkDate` will have value 2012.

Comment: it will be much better if you can trim down your code, and make one small and self-executable code that demonstrate your JSON problem.  Quoting all those JDBC code is not going to help

Comment: okay i'll edit my question.

Comment: and please also clearly state which JSON library you are using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change code:

```
String checkArray = obj.getString("checkArray");
```

to following code:

```
JSONArray checkArray = obj.getJSONArray("checkArray");
JSONObject checkObj = checkArray.getJSONObject(0);
int ptchkNumber = checkObj.getInt("ptchkNumber");
```

because key `checkArray` is array inside JSON, so you cannot using `getString()` but `getJSONArray()` instead.

**Update:**

To get each object inside array, you can iterate and access each object:

```
JSONArray checkArray = obj.getJSONArray("checkArray");
JSONObject checkObj;
for (int itemIndex=0, totalObject = checkArray.length(); itemIndex < totalObject; itemIndex++) {     
    checkObj = checkArray.getJSONObject(itemIndex);
    int ptchkNumber = checkObj.getInt("ptchkNumber");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Zamrony. This works for me. I have a follow up question. What if I have multiple entries inside my `checkArray` key? For example, another set of ptchkDate,ptchNumber, and so on.. How should I handle this? Thanks.

Comment: `checkArray` have `length()` method which returns how many object inside array. You can iterate to get each object using something like `checkArray.getJONObject(itemIndex)`